# Разбить строку с помощью regex

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Помогите, пожалуйста написать регулярку, чтобы разбить такую строку

```
(2.0) больше 1.20; меньше 4.40; (2.5) больше 1.49; меньше 2.75; (3.25)
больше 2.00; меньше 1.92; (3.5) больше 2.20; меньше 1.72; (4.0) больше
2.95; меньше 1.40; (4.5) больше 3.60; меньше 1.29;
```

через каждое второе ";", на такие строки:

```
(2.0) больше 1.20; меньше 4.40;
(2.5) больше 1.49; меньше 2.75;
...
```

Я остановился на этом выражении:

```
\(\d\.\d\d*\).{6}
```

Вывод такой:

(2.0) �����
 (2.5) �����
 (3.25) �����
 (3.5) �����
 (4.0)
�����
 (4.5) �����

Кириллицу не распознает. Запускаю в NetBeans.

Comment: Вам обязательно использовать регулярные выражения? Можно сделать проще.

Comment: В принципе не обязательно

Comment: через каждое второе ";"  - это куда принадлежит? Отформатируйте пожалуйста вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно вот так:

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
String s = "(2.0) больше 1.20; меньше 4.40; (2.5) больше 1.49; меньше 2.75; (3.25) больше 2.00; меньше 1.92; (3.5) больше 2.20; меньше 1.72; (4.0) больше 2.95; меньше 1.40; (4.5) больше 3.60; меньше 1.29;";
Pattern.compile("\\([^;]*;[^;]*;");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find())
    arrayList.add(m.group(0));
```

Comment: Спасибо, это то что надо.